# How can I show this real continuous monotonically increasing function is an open map?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

F:[a,b]->[c,d] with F(a) = c and F(b) = d.

I need to show that given an open set in [a,b], say (e,f), F((e,f)) is an open set in [c,d]. Since it is monotonically increasing, I know F(e) and F(f) bounds F((e,f)) such that F(e) < F((e,f)) < F(f). 
Intuitively, I also understand that F((e,f)) is (F(e),F(f)), but I don't know how to prove this.

What I am trying to do in the long run is prove F-1: [c,d] -> [a,b] is continuous.

Comment: The standard way to show that two sets are equal is to show that each contains the other. That $F((e,f))$ is contained in $(F(e),F(f))$ can be shown from monotonicity. That $(F(e),F(f))$ is contained in $F((e,f))$ can be shown by continuity.

Comment: @Joe How can (F(e),F(f)) contained in F((e,f)) be shown by continuity? Did you use the limit or topological definition of continuity?

Comment: You can take any point $y \in (F(e),F(f))$, and show that there must be a sequence of points $x_n \in (e,f)$ such that $f(x_n) \to y$. Every continuous function is sequentially continuous, so that means that for $lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$, we have $f(x) = y$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $F$ is increasing, $F$ in injective. Since $F(a)=c$ and $F(b)=d$, the intermediate value theorem implies $F$ is surjective. Since $F$ is a continuous bijection between Hausdorff compact spaces, $F$ is a homeomorphism. Because for each closed set $C’$ of $[c,d]$, a set $F^{-1}(C’)$ is closed in $[a,b]$ as a preimage of a closed set; for each closed set $C$ of $[a,b]$, a set $F(C)$ is compact and so closed in $[c,d]$.